# Which Sci-Fi work introduced the idea of "Consciousness Backup/ Transfer"?

Tags: history-of

I have encountered *Consciousness Backup/ Transfer* technologies countless times in science fiction. Its purpose is achieving indirect immortality most of the time. Some examples on top of my head:

- The main theme of *Altered Carbon* (2018) Netflix series is transfer of consciousness to a different biological body (for rich, that's even their own clone).
- The Doctor *saved* River Song to The Library in Doctor Who (2005) episode *Forest of the Dead* (2008).
- In *Star Trek: Picard* (2020) TV series, Picard's consciousness was transferred to a synth which looks like him. The same series also showed Data's consiousness saved into cyberspace.

Which Sci-Fi work first showed technology capable of consciousness backup/ transfer?

**Bonus Question:** Which Sci-Fi work first showed transfer of consiousness into one's clone (a subset of previous question)?

Comment: I think both are Bester's *The World of Null A* as I described here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/222721/101407

Comment: This is far too vague to be sensibly answered. On top of that, the concept of 'possession of others bodies' is clearly mythological

Comment: Is this basically a question about [mind uploading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_uploading)? If so, see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235125/what-was-the-first-sci-fi-reference-to-ones-life-being-leaving-the-biological-a/ and my summary of "The Infinite Brain" from 1930...as for transferring consciousness into a clone, I don't know if it's the first, but an early example is *The City and the Stars* from 1956

Comment: @Hypnosifl likely has correct answer with with the link that mentions both the movie Metropolis 1927 or the story The Infinite Brain 1930.  I was originally going to say the Great Race of Yith have been doing conciousness transfers to cheat death since 1936 - but that's likely not technological.

Comment: @DavidW Did you mean Van Vogt?

Comment: Anyway, I think the answer will be one of the ones at the question  @DavidW linked to.

Comment: @Spencer Yes, of course I do.  I realized that about 30 seconds too late to edit my comment.  I figure around here everybody knows what I meant anyway. :)

Comment: John Varley explored this quite a bit in various *Nine Worlds* stories, but I'm sure there are earlier examples. Certainly if we include consciousness transfer (eg Heinlein's *I Shall Fear No Evil*). I'm not so sure about the earliest stories involving backup to some kind of electronic (etc) storage system (rather than to a biological brain).  And I guess we need to distinguish between static storage, and systems where the backed-up / uploaded mind can be actively conscious.

Comment: @Valorum I clearly talked about technology. And, the question also doesn't mention anything about fantasy genre.

Comment: @Umbrella Corporation - Not sure if this helps, but the Wiki entry on 'mind uploading' has a section on history that provides quite afew early links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_uploading_in_fiction#Early_and_particularly_important_examples